# Python: How to Clear the io.BitsIO in-memory stream for Flask

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, io

I have this code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random
import io
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test1')
  def test1():
  return render_template('test1.html')

@app.route('/fig')
def plot():

  fig = Figure()
  axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
  xs = range(100)
  ys = [random.randint(1, 2) for x in xs]
  axis.plot(xs, ys)

  output = io.BytesIO()
  fig.savefig(output)
  output.seek(0)

  return send_file(output, mimetype='image/png')

if __name__ =='__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I change the values of the plot, for example:

```
ys = [random.randint(1, 50) for x in xs]
```

the page "/test1" doesn't update automatically. Only updates when

```
@app.route('/fig')
```

changes, for example, to:

```
@app.route('/fig1')
```

but, obviously, it is useless.

Help me, please!

Comment: That doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the `BytesIO` object. Something is probably getting cached at a different level, for example, in the browser cache.

Comment: usually in browser you can use `Ctrl+F5` or `Ctrl + Shift + R` to reload page without using `cache`. You can also add some random argument to url in HTML/template - `<img src="/fig?argument">` - and browser will treat it as different url and read from server. In template you can use current time as argument - you can send it as parameter to template - `render_template('test1.html', argument=datetime.datetime.now())` and in template `/fig?{{ argument }}`. Or you could use JavaScript to add this after loading page.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue while trying to send Excel files as a Bytes object in a Dash app.

Try using BytesIO.flush

`output = io.BytesIO()`
`fig.savefig(output)`
`# add next line here`
**`output.flush()`**
`output.seek(0)`

Here are some links that might be helpful:

- https://groups.google.com/g/django-developers/c/_ZcdWE9c2z8/m/y6EcHRaYmX8J
- https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/io/BytesIO/flush/python-bytesio-flush-method-examples.html